Convert specific emails to PDFs with Adobe PDFMaker using Outlook VBA
I need to convert the same four emails to pdfs every day, with specific names including the date. I need to use the Adobe PDFMaker addin in Microsoft Outlook to do this.
I wrote a macro. It properly calls the PDFMaker addin. When it tries to save, I get

An Error Occurred while saving the Adobe PDF File

I'm not sure if that's an issue with my code or an issue trying to save.
An Error Occurred while saving the Adobe PDF File
In my macro below, the things in [brackets] are names I replaced for anonymity/security/privacy/etc, so ignore the errors they would cause. (I used chatGPT to help write this code.)
Sub SaveEmailsAsPDFWithPDFMaker()

    ' Object variables
    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Dim pdfMaker As Object
    ' String variables
    Dim pdfFileName As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim fullSavePath As String
    Dim emailReceivedDate As String
    Dim emailSubject As String
    ' Integer variables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim emailCount As Integer

    ' Define the save path
    savePath = "C:\Users\[me]\Documents\macro test\"

    ' Get the PDFMaker object from COM add-ins
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pdfMaker = Application.COMAddIns.Item("PDFMOutlook.PDFMOutlook").Object
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' send message if PDFMaker is not available
    If pdfMaker Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "PDFMaker add-in is not available.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Get the count of selected emails
    emailCount = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count

    ' Loop through selected emails
    For i = 1 To emailCount
        If TypeOf Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i) Is MailItem Then
            Set objMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)

            ' Get the subject of the email
            emailSubject = objMail.Subject
            Debug.Print "Processing email: " & emailSubject

            ' Get the received date of the email in the desired format
            emailReceivedDate = Format(objMail.ReceivedTime, "m-d-yy")
            Debug.Print "Received date: " & emailReceivedDate

            ' Generate the file name based on the subject line
            If Left(emailSubject, 47) = "[Email 1 Subject]" Then
                pdfFileName = "[Email 1] " & emailReceivedDate & ".pdf"
            ElseIf Left(emailSubject, 14) = "[Email 2 Subject]" Then
                pdfFileName = "[Email 2] " & emailReceivedDate & ".pdf"
            ElseIf Left(emailSubject, 18) = "[Email 3 Subject]" Then
                pdfFileName = "[Email 3] " & emailReceivedDate & ".pdf"
            ElseIf Left(emailSubject, 17) = "[Email 4 Subject]" Then
                pdfFileName = "[Email 4] " & emailReceivedDate & ".pdf"
            Else
                MsgBox "Email '" & emailSubject & "' does not match expected subject formats.", vbExclamation
                GoTo ContinueLoop
            End If

            ' Convert email to PDF and save
            On Error Resume Next
            pdfMaker.CreatePDF savePath & pdfFileName
            
            'Error message if it fails to convert
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Failed to convert email '" & emailSubject & "' to PDF. Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0


ContinueLoop:
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Selected emails have been processed.", vbInformation
End Sub


You need to do some debugging. Did you run the code line by line, checking variable values? Especially I think about the final path / file name. Is it as you expect for any file at all? If not, how does it differ from expected? You don't need to reveal the actual filenames here, but if there's something you are unsure about, you must provide something we can discuss, e.g. all a..z you can mangle but all other characters you should show as they are.

Does the target folder exist?

For clarification: I’ve gone through debugging, and the save path and file name do match with what I expect. I’ve even tried hardcoding the save path and file name in for testing purposes. The folder definitely exists. I’ll try saving to a simpler folder maybe.
